# Как в EF6 Code-First можно установить для колонки типа Datetime значение DEFAULT statement_timestamp()

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

Как в EF6 с помощью Code-First можно установить для колонки типа Datetime значение по умолчанию в текущую дату добавления "statement_timestamp()"? В качестве БД используется PostgreSql.

```
namespace EFPostgresExperiments.model
{
    [Table("Logs", Schema = "public")]
    public class Logs
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 ID { get; set; }
        public String ErrorType { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogsConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Logs>
    {
        public LogsConfig()
        {
            this.Property(p => p.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
            this.Property(p => p.ErrorLevel).HasColumnName("ErrorType").IsRequired();
            this.Property(p => p.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsRequired();
            this.Property(p => p.Date).HasColumnName("Date").IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

UPD:

На данный момент найдено только решение с использованием прямых запросов непосредственно после создания базы. Но конечно хотелось бы менее агрессивных методов из встроенных средств EF.

```
namespace EFPostgresExperiments.model
{
    public PGContext() : base("PGDatabase") 
    {
        if (!this.Database.Exists()) 
        {
            this.Database.Create();
            this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE \"Logs\" ALTER COLUMN \"Date\" SET DEFAULT statement_timestamp()");
        }
    }
}
```